# Getting specific data live from webpage

Tags: android, c++, neural-network

Not a question for code, but rather what to read up on. 
Ive made a project where i feed a neutral network a dataset from multiple txt files, and the system tries to predict if it will rain for the next hour.

The files contain different data points for each 30 min from more than 1 year (more then 17k points in each file) 
One file contain temperatur, another preasure, Dew point, time of day and so on.

The data format in the files are like this:

:17:17:16:x:18:....

With : deviding data points. 
In the case of an x, it means there was No data point, and an average from before and after the point will be used.

Now all this works fine, and I have some what okay predictions.

What i dont know how to do is, how do I make a c++ Command to go to a website and gather specific data, A page like the one in the image.

Are there Any specific libary that would be good to use to get the data. 
My program would once every 30min call a funktion that should get the information from the webpage. Put i into the network and into the txt files for later use

I can write everything except the actual gathering from the webpage.

Any suggestions for a good libary to use?

[image]

Comment: Questions asking for recommendations are off topic on SO. Personally I would use python to gather the information.